# HTML5 File API: How to see the result of readAsText()

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

When `readAsText()` function is completed the result is stored in `.result`

How do I see if the content of the file read are correct in `.result`?

```
 fr = new FileReader();
 fr.readAsText(file);
 var x = fr.result;
 console.log(x); //does not display anything on console
```

Now how do I display the `.result` object to verify the the content?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`readAsText` is asynchronous, so you would need to use the `onload` callback to see the result.

Try something like this,

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e) {
    // e.target.result should contain the text
};
fr.readAsText(file);
```

Further information here,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader

Comment: how we will get "file" attribute passed to fr.readAsText(file);, please help

Comment: `var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.result)
};
fr.readAsText(file);`

this will print the read file

Answer (score 5):

This took me like 300 hours to figure out even after reading the documentation and examples online...

**Here's some actual, working code:**

```js
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    alert(fileReader.result);
};
inputElement.onchange = function(event) {
    fileReader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

---

Also, [FYI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

> **FileReader.onabort**
> A handler for the `abort` event. This event is triggered each time the reading operation is aborted.
>
> **FileReader.onerror**
> A handler for the `error` event. This event is triggered each time the reading operation encounter an error.
>
> **FileReader.onload**
> A handler for the `load` event. This event is triggered each time the reading operation is successfully completed.

Comment: Best answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

```js
async FileUploadHandler(e){
  let readInputFile = await inputFileReader(e);
}

async inputFileReader(event){
  return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    let input = event.target;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      res(reader.result)
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  });
},
```

```html
<input type="file" on-change="FileUploadHandler" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete html and vanilla javascript example that creates a simple file input and a file reader that reads the file with `FileReader.readAsText()`then writes the text content of that file to the console. This works well for files like .txt or .csv.

There are also `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`, `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()`, and `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` which might work better for other use cases. I also recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Note: Users can select multiple files to include in the input, this code will only read the first of those files (as you can see in the reference to the [0] element in `event.target.files`.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.onload = function(event) {
        document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
      }

      function handleFileSelect(event) {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(event) {
          console.log(event.target.result);
        }
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        fileReader.readAsText(file);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was the fastest option to get running for me.   Is there a way to simply "hard-code" the file name?  I've tried "inspecting" the event.target.files[0], and cannot see where the actual path/filename is placed.   This would save me a few clicks in having to select it each time.

Comment: I don't think that's possible as this is granting access to the host file system and that is probably protected. I suspect that allowing arbitrary websites to select the file they want to download might have security implications.

Comment: You might be able to drag and drop the file onto the button though.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the File API is poorly documented. The `readAsText` method is called before `onload`.

```
let onFileChange = (event) => {
  let file = event.target.files[0];

  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsText(file);

  fileReader.onload = (event) => {
    let fileAsText = event.target.result;
    console.log(fileAsText);
  };
};
```

```
<form>
  <input type="file" onChange={onFileChange} />
</form>
```