# Read an input tag into a javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

I'm trying to read an input type="file" tag into a javascript string. I know this should be simple but I simply cannot get my code to work.  The file is plain .html.  Here's what I have

```
    <h3>Select location of html file.</h3>
    <form onSubmit="submitButtonPressed()">
    <input type="file" id="classList" />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var htmlFile = document.getElementById("classList").files[0];   //read the file selected with the <input> tag
        reader.readAsText(htmlFile);            
        var htmlText = reader.result;  //and create a string with the contents

        function submitButtonPressed() {
             var lengthOfText = htmlText.length;
             alert("It is " + lengthOfText + " characters long");
        }
    </script>
```

I'm just trying to create a string that contains the contents of the .html file selected by the input tag.  I can't figure out why htmlText doesn't contain the contents of the .html file, could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

this is the right answer for you :

[HTML5 File API: How to see the result of readAsText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729301/html5-file-api-how-to-see-the-result-of-readastext)

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    // e.target.result should contain the text
};
reader.readAsText(file);
```

so i guess you will have to check on pressing the button if the file was loaded or not , maybe it is still in progress , or encountered an error

Comment: I don't understand what needs to go in the onload function though, what is the variable e supposed to be?  Thanks for the reply though

Comment: var htmlText = reader.result;  //and create a string with the contents should be inside the on load function to ensure that data was loaded