# FileRead() store content into class variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filereader

I have this code in Angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-route',
  templateUrl: './add-route.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-route.component.scss']
})
export class AddRouteComponent {
  public fileContent: string;

    constructor() { }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    }

    getFile(event) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      let filename = file.name;
      let result;

      if((filename.split('.').pop()) === 'gpx') {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        this.fileContent = // what should be here?
      }
   }  

}
```

I would like to access the file from input file from the form (which must be type of .gpx), get the content (using FileReader()). How can I store filecontent once upon its loaded into **class variable fileContent**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729301/html5-file-api-how-to-see-the-result-of-readastext

Comment: Well, this doesnt work. When I add         reader.onload = function (e) {
            result = e.target.result;
        } this.fileContent = result;  and print it to console its undefined. Yea, the result its stored in the e.target.result but my question is- how can I store it in the class variable.

Comment: My *guess*: `reader.onload = (e: any) => { this.fileContent = e.target.result; };`

Comment: No, that does not working. Its still undefined.

Comment: Can you add, or show the code you are using to check `this.fileContent`? You would need to do that in the same `{ }` block where the variable gets set. So, something like this: `reader.onload = (e: any) => { this.fileContent = e.target.result; console.log(this.fileContent); };` Checking outside of that would always return undefined.

Comment: Yea I was calling that outside of a function. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results of `readAsText` function in Typescript, you need to set up an arrow function for the `onload` event that the `FileReader` fires.

```
getFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const filename = file.name;

  if ((filename.split('.').pop()) === 'gpx') {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
        this.fileContent = e.target.result;
        console.log(this.fileContent);
    };
  }
}
```

Then, from within the body of the arrow function, you can access the file contents via the `e.target.result` (`e` being the event). From there, you can do what you like the data.