# How to use readAsText() within a Jasmine test and alert the result?

Tags: javascript, csv, jasmine, filereader

I'm trying to test a function, that returns a `Blob` of a CSV, it has a type, name etc and alerting that returns this:

```
Object{size: 9, type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;', name: 'Test'}
```

and it is an `instanceOf Blob` as well.

I tried doing this consulting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729301/html5-file-api-how-to-see-the-result-of-readastext)...

```
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e) {
  return e.target.result;
};
alert(fr.readAsText(blob));
alert(blob instanceof Blob);
```

Though no luck, the first alert call just returns `undefined`.

```
ALERT: undefined
ALERT: true
```

Any help with doing this? How can I convert the CSV blob content to a String that I can then read and test the result of the content in the CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually was with something else within the test mocking the CSV/blob creation, particularly `ngMocks` so the blob wasn't actually being created.

If you have a similar case doing this in a Jasmine test, may be your situation as well. To get around this, I mocked the function that creates/organizes the content of the blob in the test and then just recorded that locally so I could test it later...rather than trying to access the blob itself.

```
this.CSV.stringify.and.callFake(function(csvFeaturesInStringify, csvOptionsInStringify) {
    this.csvFeatures = csvFeaturesInStringify;
    this.csvOptions= csvOptionsInStringify;
    return {
      then: function(successCallback) {
        successCallback("geometry,LAT,LONG,name,marker-color");
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

FileReader is an asynchronous library. When you assign a function to `fr.onload`, FileReader will call that function with the data when it loads a file. That means your data is only available inside that function and you cannot get it to the outer scope. You want to do something like this:

```
var fr = new FileReader(); // Create FileReader instance

// Assign a function to be called when FileReader reads a file
fr.onload = function(e) {

  // Your data is available in this scope only. Returning it does nothing.
  alert(e.target.result);
  alert(blob instanceof Blob);
};

fr.readAsText(blob); // Tell our instance of FileReader to read `blob`
```